# module documentation not getting generated for all python modules in a package

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I have following directories structure.

```
$ tree emaildiff/
|____
| |______init__.py
| |______init__.pyc
| |____mail
| | |____.DS_Store
| | |______init__.py
| | |______init__.pyc
| | |____send.py
| | |____send.pyc
| |____maildiff_cmd.py
| |____maildiff_cmd.pyc
| |____version.py
| |____version.pyc
```

and I have two pages for code for maildiff and send

```
$ tree docs/source/
| |____
| | |_____static
| | |_____templates
| | |____conf.py
| | |____index.rst
| | |____maildiff.rst
| | |____send.rst
| | |____terminal.glue
```

based on the

what I have

```
.. automodule:: maildiff_cmd
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :inherited-members:
    :show-inheritance:
```

and for send.py

```
.. automodule:: send
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :inherited-members:
    :show-inheritance:
```

and in the conf.py I have inserted the python module path as

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../../emaildiff'))
```

but still I get the error while doing make html

```
====================================
/Development/pyclones/git-maildiff/docs/source/maildiff.rst:13: WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module u'maildiff_cmd'; the following exception was raised:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sphinx/ext/autodoc.py", line 385, in import_object
    __import__(self.modname)
  File "/Development/pyclones/git-maildiff/emaildiff/maildiff_cmd.py", line 14, in <module>
    import emaildiff.mail.send as send
ImportError: No module named emaildiff.mail.send
/Development/pyclones/git-maildiff/docs/source/send.rst:7: WARNING: Title underline too short.
```

2nd error below:

```
Welcome to maildiff git command documentation!
====================================
/Development/pyclones/git-maildiff/docs/source/send.rst:13: WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module u'send'; the following exception was raised:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sphinx/ext/autodoc.py", line 385, in import_object
    __import__(self.modname)
ImportError: No module named send
```

so if I include

```
sys.path.insert(1, os.path.abspath('../../emaildiff/mail'))
```

the 2nd error goes away and docs gets generated for send.py but emaildiff/mailddiff_cmd.py never gets generated.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `sys.path.insert(1, os.path.abspath('../../'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working,

I had to include each one of the module location path to be inserted explicitly even though I had __init__.py file siting beside the actual modules.

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../../'))
sys.path.insert(1, os.path.abspath('../../emaildiff'))
sys.path.insert(2, os.path.abspath('../../emaildiff/mail'))
```

Comment: It seems as though the order in which paths are inserted are important. Therefore if anyone stumbling upon this is using `sys.path.append` instead of `sys.path.insert` change that. It tripped me up quite a bit.